# Is Initial View Controller does work?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a viewcontroller and a tab bar controller. I want to change view controller as initial view controller and create a segue to show tab bar controller.

I have tried to set the new initial view controller. There are 2 ways. First, check the tick box "Is Initial View Controller". Second, drag the arrow to new screen. It does not show any error, but it shows the tab bar controller as usual and I can't find the view controller either.

[image]

Anyone know how to what is going on. Please tell me to fix. Thanks

Comment: show your storyboard

Comment: Provide Navigation controller for your Initial view Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `UINavigationViewController` and connect it up in the hierarchy in a similar fashion to:

[image: UINavigationController Hookup]

The leftmost view is the "view" that you mention, which needs to show the UITabViewController.

I've added a button for ease of use.

The next along (send from the left) is the UINavigationViewController. No settings on here need to be set etc... it's pretty much "plug and play" as to put it.

The next view (third from the left) is the UITabViewController (with corresponding views to it's immediate right).

The connection between the UINavigationViewController and the UITabViewController is "rootViewController" as the Tab View is the "root view controller" e.g. the primary view controller.

The segue between the first view, and the navigation view controller is merely a "show" segue. I liked directly between the button and the navigation controller in Xcode.

Hope this mash-up helps!

*Edit* I wrote a quick mask up of what I posted in the images for you to play with: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61211034/Stackoverflow/NavgationViewController.zip

Answer (score 0):

Based on your storyboard's image, looks like you don't have any **NavigationController** embedded to your root **LoginViewController**, try this:

1. Select your **LoginViewController** on your storyboard
2. Then in **xcode Menu bar** at the **top**, go to **Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller** (as you can see in the image below)
3. Then your **NavigationController** will be set as your **Initial View Controller**, and see your **LoginViewController** be displayed and work as expected your segue.

[image: Setting NavigationController to the root view controller.]